# Is there a way to assign an integer to a component in Unity/C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to assign a public integer in my script to a value in another script. It should be simple, but when running code below

```
public int objectIndex = GetComponent<TargetComponent>().index;
```

it gives me an error

Am I missing something?

````
A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Component.GetComponent<TargetComponent>()'
``` is the error I get.
````

Comment: Field initialization happens before your constructor, so there is no `this` to reference yet (your code is actually a shorthand for `this.GetComponent<TargetComponent>().index`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying that you can't use GetComponent when initializing a field.

This should be done either through the inspector, or through the [start](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html)/[awake](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) methods.

e.g

```
public int objectIndex;

void Awake()
{
    objectIndex = GetComponent<TargetComponent>().index;
}
//OR
void Start()
{
    objectIndex = GetComponent<TargetComponent>().index;
}
```

Or, if you want to do it through the inspector, you can serialize the field and set it directly inside of the Unity editor.

```
[SerializeField] public TargetComponent objectIndex;
```

In the inspector you can assign the TargetComponent component through the inspector. Then you would acess the index by doing `objectIndex.index`